# Where can I find a list of all supported B2C custom policy Claim Transformation Methods?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Where can I find a list of all supported Azure AD B2C Custom Policy Claims Transformation Methods?

I have searched Google, Bing, DuckDuckGo and GitHub for such list, but can't find it.

And TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd schema doesn't contain it.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md - does have an outdated list - some of methods like `AddParameterToStringCollection` can't be used - policy can't be imported when I use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No such list exists at this time.** You should request it via the [Azure AD B2C feedback forum](https://aka.ms/aadb2cuv).

**Your best bet is to go through all the [starter packs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) and see which transformations are included in those**. While there might be others, if they are not referenced in the starter packs or docs, they are unsupported and not recommended for broad use.

Comment: [This feedback item](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32574223-add-documentation-for-b2c-custom-policy-metadata-f) seems like a decent fit

Answer (score 1):

Update!

We have released a full documentation of the schema here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimstransformations

All elements of custom policies for b2c, also known as Identity Experience Framework or IEF are published.